# Undefined function when calling a constructor param closure function

Tags: php

Considering the following class :

```
class MyClass {

    public function __construct($mailProvider) {
        $this->mailProvider = $mailProvider;

        echo get_class($mailProvider());
        echo get_class($this->mailProvider());
    }

}
```

And the following call  :

```
$mailProvider = function () {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    return $mail;
};

$myClass = new MyClass($mailProvider);
```

I can't figure why the second echo would cause a call to an undefined function.

Anyone can figure it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because PHP will look for the method $this->mailProvider() before looking for a property $this->mailProvider. You need to dereference the property by wrapping it in parentheses:

```
echo get_class(($this->mailProvider)());
```

Comment: So obvious! Thanks !